# Change HyperLink Control to Href doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a Hyper Link control is added to panel and it worked. I need to replace it as href for consistent other controls in page. However my script has error when I debug it in VS 2015.  The error message is : "JavaScript critical error at line 333, column 255 in http://localhost:603/Order/buyerProfile.aspx?Id=42940\n\nSCRIPT1002: Syntax error"

Would someone tell me how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

There is my code for HperLink control that work:

```
Dim hypOrder As New HyperLink
Dim onClick As String = "openWin('OrderForm/pop.aspx"
                onClick &= "','',500,270);return false;"
                hypOrder.Text = "Test page"
                hypOrder.Attributes.Add("onclick", onClick)
pnlLink.Controls.Add(hypOrder )
```

There is my code to change as href:

```
dim href1 as string
Dim href1 As String = "<a target='_blank'  class='body'" & "href='#'"
href1 = href1 & " onclick='openWin('OrderForm/pop.aspx','',500,270);return false;"
href1 = href1 & "'>" & Test page & "</a>"
 Dim ltLink As New Literal
 ltLink.Text = href1
 pnlSecurityFlagsLink.Controls.Add(ltLink)
```

I debug it the href text is :

```
  <a target='_blank'  class='body' href='#' onclick='openWin('OrderForm/pop.aspx','',500,270);return false;'>Test page </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple single quotes on the line inside the `onclick=`. You have to use double quotes to make it work.

```
href1 = href1 & " onclick=""openWin('OrderForm/pop.aspx','',500,270);return false;"">Link</a>"
```

To escape the `"`, make it a double `""`

Comment: @VEWWD, would you help me again. I forget to add the order id on the url by code. I modified the code as below but it show the text not href. dim id as integer=Cint(txt.text)    href = href & " onclick=""openWin(''OrderForm/pop.aspx'?cId=" & m_Id & " ','',500,270);return false;"">" & Link & "</a>"

Comment: It should be `onclick=""openWin('OrderForm/pop.aspx?cid=" & m_Id & "','',500,270);return false;"">Link</a>"`. You added a `'` after the .aspx.  `.aspx'?cid`. It does not belong there.